# How do I UseMiddleware<Type>(...) and pass in options?

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm trying to understand how the ASP.NET Core pipeline works. I would like to use the `StaticFileMiddleware` and pass in some options.

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    var staticFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions();
    app.UseMiddleware<Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware>(staticFileOptions);
}
```

When I run my application I get the following error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware' could not be located. Ensure the type is concrete and services are registered for all parameters of a public constructor.
    at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.UseMiddlewareExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<UseMiddleware>b__0(RequestDelegate next)
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.Internal.ApplicationBuilder.Build()
    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

I understand that I can just use

```
app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileOptions);
```

But, as this is a learning exercise, I want to call it the other way.

Comment: This is a better answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501028/how-to-pass-primitive-data-to-asp-net-core-middleware

Answer (score 8):

This is my approach to the same problem.

Just create new class with properties which you want to pass:

```
public class LoggingOption
{
    public bool ToLog { get; set; }
}
```

This is how to init

```
app.UseMiddleware<LoggingMiddleware>(Options.Create(new LoggingOption{ ToLog = true }));
```

And this is constructor

```
 public LoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IOptions<LoggingOption> options)
        {
            _next = next;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<LoggingMiddleware>();
            _toLog = options.Value.ToLog;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Most middleware's actually take their options not just as the pure class itself, such as in your case `StaticFileOptions`, but rather wrapped inside the `IOptions` configuration interface as `IOptions<StaticFileOptions>`.

Fortunately there is a nice method available to you for just this. So you can pass the return value of `Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(staticFileOptions)` instead into the `UseMiddleware` call.

Having to wrap inside IOptions might seem redundant and so forth, but there are benefits to it, such as automatically reloading values when your configuration source (file system, Azure App Configration, etc etc) changes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
app.UseMiddleware<Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware>(staticFileOptions);
```

use

```
app.UseMiddleware<Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware>(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(staticFileOptions));
```

(or stick the `Microsoft.Extensions.Options` as a using and call `Options.Create`)

This is how UseStaticFiles is implemented in the [actual code](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/StaticFileExtensions.cs)

Answer (score -2):

According to your error

> System.InvalidOperationException: A suitable constructor for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware' could not be located. **Ensure** the type is concrete and **services are registered for** all parameters of **a public constructor**.

add public constructor or your constructor is private

Comment: This is actually wrong. This error has nothing to do with having a public constructor or not. The error will be thrown when no matching constructor is found, or at least one of the services the constructor requires as parameter cannot be found

Comment: Actually it does! and that was the case for me !