# How to pass primitive data to asp.net core middleware

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to pass some data into a ASP NET CORE middleware

e.g. if this is a list of strings, do you use the same mechanism as passing in a service?

e.g. add it as a parameter to the Invoke method and register it with the DI?

If so, how do you do the registration for primitive types? e.g. a lsit of strings. does it have to be a named type or something like that?

Or can we pass the data in some other way?

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's suppose we have a middleware:

```
public class FooMiddleware
{
    public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, List<string> list)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
}
```

Just pass a list to `UseMiddleware` call to resolve it **per-middleware**:

```
app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>(new List<string>());
```

You could create a DTO and pass it:

```
public FooMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, Payload payload)
....
app.UseMiddleware<FooMiddleware>(new Payload());
```

Or register this DTO in DI container, it will be resolved in middleware:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<Payload>(new Payload());
}
```

In addition, DI container allows to resolve **per-request** dependencies:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, IMyScopedService svc)
{
    svc.MyProperty = 1000;
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

[Documentation:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware#writing-middleware)

> Because middleware is constructed at app startup, not per-request,
>   *scoped* lifetime services used by middleware constructors are not shared with other dependency-injected types during each request. If
>   you must share a *scoped* service between your middleware and other
>   types, add these services to the `Invoke` method's signature. The
>   `Invoke` method can accept additional parameters that are populated by
>   dependency injection.